# How to interpret big self-time results in Java Visual VM?

Tags: java, visualvm

Trying to profile my app, I found in `Sampler` section of `Java Visual VM`, that method `MyClass#setDimensionValue(int)` takes the most time.

But the code of this method is following:

```
    public int setDimensionValue(int index, int newValue) {
        return delegate.setValue(index, newValue);
    }
```

i.e. it just calls another method.

How it can spend so much time inside caller method then?

Answer (score 1):

First prove that JVisualVM is accurately telling you the truth and you are interpreting the profiling results correctly.

Add this typical profiling pattern to the suspected slow code block:

```
public int setDimensionValue(int index, int newValue) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int result = delegate.setValue(index, newValue);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.printf("Duration in %dms%n", end - start);

    return result;
}
```

Next, swap delgate.setValue with a [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) delegate with your own setValue method and with the timing code prove there is no bottleneck.

Next, put timing in the setValue method inside the delegate.

Perhaps the delegator performs operations with latency such as setValue on a webservice?

Observe the thread states in JVisualVM.  Is anything blocking?  Ensure that another thread does not have a [synchronization lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) on delegate and there are no locks on objects within the call stack inside delegate.setValue

Call the setDimensionValue method from a unit test.  A unit testing framework will also give you accurate timing statistics.  When unit testing objects instances such as delegator should be easily be mockable.

Lastly, ensure that at the time this method is executed your CPU and heap space appear unstressed.